# How to make a private notification pusher in Laravel

Tags: laravel, push-notification

Hello i am working in laravel with notification pusher. I have two separate projects Project A is the backend of the pusher and Project B is the front-end that receives and shows the push notification. So far have managed to do the public pusher and works great but i have been facing difficulties to do the private one. I will share both my codes public pusher and private pusher so you can see the modifications i have done.

**Public Pusher**

**Project A:**

Controller:

```
event(new NonBelongingAnimalsEvent($animalCode, $le_code, $message, $userId));
```

In controller i have this event trigger that i pass,

Event:

```
class NonBelongingAnimalsEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $animalCode;

    public $message;

    public $le_code;

    public $userId;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($animalCode,$le_code, $message, $userId)
    {
        $this->animalCode = $animalCode;
        $this->le_code = $le_code;
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['notifications'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'non-belonging-animals';
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => $this->message];
    }
}
```

broadcasting.php :

```
 'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
            ],
        ],
```

**Project B:**

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Pusher Test</title>
    <script src="https://js.pusher.com/8.2.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('PUBLIC_PUSHER_KEY', {
            cluster: 'eu'
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifications');
        channel.bind('non-belonging-animals', function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pusher Test</h1>
<p>
    Try publishing an event to channel <code>my-channel</code>
    with event name <code>my-event</code>.
</p>
</body>
```

Now this is the public pusher and works good, i will show now what i have done for private channel, that is not working.

**Private Pusher**

**Project A**

Controller:

```
event(new NonBelongingAnimalsEvent($animalCode, $le_code, $message, $userId));
```

Event:

```
class NonBelongingAnimalsEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $animalCode;

    public $message;

    public $le_code;

    public $userId;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($animalCode,$le_code, $message, $userId)
    {
        $this->animalCode = $animalCode;
        $this->le_code = $le_code;
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        //return ['notifications'];
        return new PrivateChannel('notifications.' . $this->userId);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'non-belonging-animals';
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => $this->message];
    }
}
```

Broadcasting.php:

```
  'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => true,
            ],
        ],
```

Channels.php:

```
Broadcast::channel('notifications.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
});
```

**Project B**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Pusher Test</title>
    <script src="https://js.pusher.com/8.2.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var pusher = new Pusher('PUBLIC_PUSHER_KEY', {
            cluster: 'eu',
            authEndpoint: 'http://project_a.test/broadcasting/auth',
            auth: {
                headers: {

                }
            }
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifications');

        channel.bind('non-belonging-animals', function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        pusher.connection.bind('error', function(error) {
            console.error('Pusher error:', error);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pusher Test</h1>
<p>
    Try publishing an event to channel <code>my-channel</code>
    with event name <code>my-event</code>.
</p>
</body>
```

This code does not work can anyone help me to understand what am i doing wrong, i couldnt find a proper tutorial or documentation for private channel, also the debug console on pusher.com i only for public channels.